# Apache 2.4: mod_alias, mod_rewrite, mod_proxy execution order

Tags: apache-2.4, mod-rewrite, rewrite, mod-proxy, mod-alias

I can't find any documentation on Apache vhosts instructions priority / execution order between

- [`mod_alias`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect) (`Redirect` instructions),
- [`mod_rewrite`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html) (`RewriteRule` instructions)
- [`mod_proxy`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html) (`ProxyPass` instructions).

Is there any documentation out there about the order these are going to be handled by Apache? Which one takes precedence over the other?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The general rule is that the order of the directives is important. The directive that comes first and matches *wins* (just like the order of the `VirtualHost` definitions – the first VHost is the default VHost).

In most cases it should work fine if you define `Alias`es/`Redirect`s and `RewriteRule`s first and proxy rules like `ProxyPass` last if you want to let redirection take place before your proxy settings apply.

http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#order

> Aliases and Redirects occurring in different contexts are processed
>   like other directives according to standard [merging
>   rules](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/sections.html#mergin). But
>   when multiple Aliases or Redirects occur in the same context (for
>   example, in the same
>   [`<VirtualHost>`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#virtualhost)
>   section) they are processed in a particular order.
>
> First, all Redirects are processed before Aliases are processed, and
>   therefore a request that matches a
>   [`Redirect`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirect)
>   or
>   [`RedirectMatch`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_alias.html#redirectmatch)
>   will never have Aliases applied. Second, the Aliases and Redirects are
>   processed in the order they appear in the configuration files, with
>   the first match taking precedence.
>
> For this reason, when two or more of these directives apply to the
>   same sub-path, you must list the most specific path first in order for
>   all the directives to have an effect.

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriterule

> The `RewriteRule` directive is the real rewriting workhorse. The
>   directive can occur more than once, with each instance defining a
>   single rewrite rule. The order in which these rules are defined is
>   important - this is the order in which they will be applied at
>   run-time.

Also see: [Apache mod_rewrite Technical Details](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/tech.html#InternalAPI)

https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass

> **Ordering ProxyPass Directives**
>   The configured [`ProxyPass`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) and [`ProxyPassMatch`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypassmatch) rules are checked in the order of configuration. The
>   first rule that matches wins. So usually you should sort conflicting
>   [`ProxyPass`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) rules starting with the longest URLs first. Otherwise, later
>   rules for longer URLS will be hidden by any earlier rule which uses a
>   leading substring of the URL. Note that there is some relation with
>   worker sharing.
>
> **Ordering ProxyPass Directives in Locations**
>   Only one [`ProxyPass`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_proxy.html#proxypass) directive can be placed in a [`Location block`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#location), and the most specific
>   location will take precedence.
>
> **Exclusions and the no-proxy environment variable**
>   Exclusions must come before the general `ProxyPass` directives. In 2.4.26 and later,
>   the "no-proxy" environment variable is an alternative to exclusions,
>   and is the only way to configure an exclusion of a `ProxyPass`
>   directive in [`Location`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/core.html#location) context. This variable should be set with
>   [`SetEnvIf`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_setenvif.html#setenvif), as [`SetEnv`](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/mod/mod_env.html#setenv) is not evaluated early enough.

Comment: Nice answer. But it would be good to also mention that mixing mod_alias Redirect/RedirectMatch with mod_rewrite RewriteRule can have unintuitive consequences. From the Apache documentation's [When not to use mod_rewrite](https://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/avoid.html#redirect) guide: "when there are Redirect and RewriteRule directives in the same scope, the RewriteRule directives will run first, regardless of the order of appearance in the configuration file." And: "a RewriteRule will usually take effect before a ProxyPass, and so may preempt what you're trying to accomplish."